# Like button think that my domain is other domain.. google.ru

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, canonical-link

In the header of my page I send `og` parameters. But the counter of the like button shows me a number near 17 000. When I use Facebook developers debug, I see that canonical url is not my url, it's google.ru, for example:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fseo-top-news.com.ua%2Fgoogle-vlojit-v-startapy-1-5-milliarda%2F

I really have a high opinion of Google, but I don't want have a Google like button on all of my articles :)
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your site may have been hacked with malicious redirects -- if you look down by the "Redirect Path" section, Facebook's crawler is being redirected to a series of super-sketchy sounding sites.

Check your `.htaccess` for anything that shouldn't be there (this is a really common vector of attack), change your FTP password, and upgrade your WordPress install (and plugins).

Comment: thank you, it realy hacked...  in plugin Contact Form 7 hole is now. script change htaccess and delicately stealing traffic.

Answer (score 1):

On the debugger result page you link to, you can see the redirect path:

original:   http://seo-top-news.com.ua/google-vlojit-v-startapy-1-5-milliarda/
302:    http://dietrussia.ru/
302:    http://webhitexpress.ru/in.cgi?2
302:    http://www.google.ru/

The Facebook scraper is being sent through to Google.

This is because of the user-agent. If I curl your site with no user agent, I also get redirected:

```
curl http://seo-top-news.com.ua/google-vlojit-v-startapy-1-5-milliarda/
```

But if I curl it with a real browser user-agent, I get the proper page:

```
curl --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1309.0 Safari/537.17" http://seo-top-news.com.ua/google-vlojit-v-startapy-1-5-milliarda/
```

The Facebook scraper uses the user-agent 'facebookexternalhit', so simply make sure that is being returned the full page content, not the 302.

Comment: THANKS! site use wordpress. in plugin Contact Form 7 hole is now. script change htaccess and delicately stealing traffic. BEWARE! and one more time - thanks.